# How to retrieve data from table "a" based on different values in table "b"

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

```
var c = from p in db.Testings
        where p.id == Convert.ToInt32(k)
        select new{p.ItemId};`
```

The above Linq is returning multiple amount of rows containing different ItemIds.
Now, I am trying to retrieve all the rows from Questions table containing all those ItemIds I got returned in the above linq. As expected, the below code is not working. Can anyone please help me with this logic or correct my code if it's a minor logical mistake.

```
 var cfk = from p in db.Questions
           where p.ItemId == Convert.ToInt32(c)
           select p;

 GridView4.DataSource = cfk;
 GridView4.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need to 'join' the tables.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do so??

Comment: I don't mean make then one table. I mean 'join' then. That is the term used in SQL to indicate that you are reading data from two tables. Read here: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
              var cfk = from p in db.Questions
              where c.Contains(p.ItemId)
              select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an inner join using LINQ.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx

I would probably do the join on the Db side during your Get() if possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your choice of 'cfk' as the second variable name I'm guessing you have setup your database such that Questions.ItemId is a foreign key into Testings, where Testings.ItemId is the primary key of Testings and Testings.id is some other non-key column.

If that is the case you can say:

```
var cfk = db.Testings
            .Where(t => t.id == k)
            .SelectMany(t => t.Questions);
```

or

```
var cfk = db.Questions
            .Where(t => t.Testing.id == k);
```

If there is no foreign key relationship you would need to do a Join as others suggest e.g.

```
var cfk = db.Testings
            .Where(t => t.id == k)
            .Join(db.Questions, t => t.ItemId, q => q.ItemId, (t, q) => q);
```